# How can my bot initiate the conversation before user types

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am building a chatbot using DialogFlow and node.js. Need to have my bot to initiate the conversation before user types a message. It would something like welcome message as soon as user clicks on Bot icon. Can this be achieved via events in default welcome intent and how? any samples would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done.
When the user clicks on the bot icon, you need to send an event to Dialogflow which will trigger the welcome intent.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done because the conversation has not started until the user sends a message.