# How to add the starter message in dialogflow ES before the user start giving inputs

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

in the **DialogFlow** ES console we can generate responses based on the user input.
I am wondering that how can I add the starter message when the user visit the chat first time like before giving any input to bot.

such as

"*Hi, this is 's bot. How can i help you?*"

Comment: Does this [link](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/dialogflow-tutorial-modify-default-welcome-and-fallback-intents-for-chatbots-purpose-6768bd663138) help you?

Comment: Thank @kiranmathew for your time, but it is not that for which i am looking. This article is talking about the change of initial default response message that will prompted after user questions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned in this stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676724/how-can-my-bot-initiate-the-conversation-before-user-types) it can be done by using dialogflow Welcome Event. You can use a welcome intent as the word WELCOME, under the Event section in the intent. It can be used as a "trigger" to get the Default Welcome Intent to fire without the user typing any message. When a user will click on the bot icon, Dialogflow will trigger the welcome intent with your desired message.

A similar post [here](https://botflo.com/get-api-ai-agent-initiate-conversation-user-types-message/) talks about this.